# How to skip circual dependency in rxjs logic?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a `drawLine$ = new Subject<boolean>()` subject into which I pass the value returned from the server.

This value `drawLine$` is displayed in interface and user can change it: `drawLine$.next(input.value)`

And there is `combineLatest ([drawLine $, ...])` which listens for the latest changes and sends it to the server for saving (autosave).

Problem is when I get data from server and pass it to `drawLine$.next(input.value)` it changes data in interface and calls again `combineLatest ([drawLine $, ...]` to send updation to server. I dont need it, because I got this data from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your combinelatest:

```
combineLatest ([drawLine $, ...])
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
```

If previous value is the same, **distinctUntilChanged** is not going to allow to pass to the following code (not pass to send the latest changes to the server for saving (autosave)).

More info about **distinctUntilChanged** [HERE](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)